# Jquery table header resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a `table` which is inside a `div`. I am resizing the table header and it is working fine if the table is outside the `div`. But if it is inside the div the resizing is not working fine.

What I am doing wrong here?

Any one help me out to do this!!

Here is the [DEMO for table inside `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/nnVp4/)

Here is the [DEMO for table without `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/vQxm5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you've given your `container` a `width:200px;`
Give it either a `width:220px;` or no width at all to adjust it properly for the `table`.

```
<div id="container" style="height:100%;overflow:auto; width:220px;">
```

Comment: Even if i give width:220px the resizing is not working fine. Could you please show me the working code

Comment: Yup it is working but i need to do it even with horizontal scrollbar inside the div

Comment: but upto my knowledge overflow:auto should work. I'm sorry if I am wrong

Comment: I think you shouldtry giving your `container` only these `height:100%; width:auto;`